# Descargar archivo automáticamente desde Api restFul con Net5

Tags: c#, api, restful, .net-5

Tengo una api restFul con Net5, en esta api tengo un controlador donde se obtiene un arreglo de bytes que corresponde a un fichero (pdf, png, jpg ...) que posteriormente debe enviarse al cliente y descargarse automáticamente en el navegador, pero al hacer mis pruebas desde Swagger lo único que obtengo es:

[image: Swagger]

Según veo no está funcionando correctamente ya que no veo por ningún lado el arreglo de bytes y solo veo los nombres de las clases en swagger.

```
    [HttpGet("{IdFichero}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ObtenerFichero(int IdFichero)
    {
    //Se obtiene el arreglo de bytes, extensión y nombre del archivo.
        DbResponseImageHub response = await _unitOfWork.MensajeRepository.ObtenerImagenMensajeRepository(IdFichero);

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(response.fichero);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Documento" + response.extension;


        switch (response.extension)
        {
            case "png":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                break;
            case "jpg":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
                break;
            case "jpeg":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
                break;
            case "bmp":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/bmp");
                break;
            case "pdf":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                break;
            case "docx":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.documen");
                break;
            case "doc":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msword");
                break;
            case "xlsx":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                break;
            case "xls":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Si me pudieran indicar que estoy haciendo mal, muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

debes de retornar el tipo correcto de la implementación de IActionResult,
en este caso FileResult.

Intenta cambiar tu `return OK(result);` por `return File(result, "image/png");`. Además, como consecuencia, declara una variable para establecer el tipo de resultado:

```cs
var tipo = "";
switch (response.extension)
{
    case "png": tipo = "image/png";
        break;
    //...
}

return File(result, tipo);
```

[Referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-file(system-byte()-system-string))